# When compiling C using MinGW gcc, why only specifing the obj name works but not using $(OBJS)?

Tags: c, gcc, makefile

I am testing the **Makefile** for **MinGW gcc** to compile this simple C file:

```
int main() {
    printf("Hello, world!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

And here is the **Makefile**:

```
SRCS := $(cmd cd dir *.c)
OBJS := $(cmd cd dir *.o)
EXE := hello.exe 

CC := gcc

$(OBJS): $(SRCS)
    $(CC) -c -O3 $< -o $@

$(EXE): $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $< -o $@
```

Running this using mingw32-make gives the alert:

```
gcc  -o hello.exe
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
Makefile:27: recipe for target 'hello.exe' failed
mingw32-make: *** [hello.exe] Error 1
```

But when I replace the **$(OBJS)** with just the **hello.o**, which looks like this:

```
$(EXE): hello.o
    $(CC) $< -o $@
```

it successfully compiled.

I am wondering why this is happening? And potential how can I fix it? As I have to scale it up to compile dozens of c files together, it's supposed to be preferable to use the $(OBJS) variable.

Comment: There are no object files before compilation, so `$(cmd cd dir *.o)` will return empty list at first. `$(var:suffix=replacement)` (`$(SRCS:.c=.o)`)will be useful to get a list of `.o` files from a list of `.c` files.

Comment: What is `$(cmd ...)`?  Is that some special feature specific to mingw32-make?  There's nothing like that in standard GNU make.

Comment: It's `-O3` (capital o, not zero).

Answer (score 0):

You made an elementary mistake:

```
OBJS := $(cmd cd dir *.o)
```

What happens when there are no `.o` files in a clean checkout of your project?

Your Makefile needs `.o` files to know what `.o` files to make!

The (semi-) correct thing to do is to calculate `OBJS` from `SRCS`.

```
OBJS := $(SRCS:.c=.o)
```

This is still hokey if you are using wildcard matching to calculate `SRCS`, because any `.c` file you happen to have laying around in the project directory can get accidentally pulled into your build.

It is best to specify the `.o` files directly, naming each one:

```
OBJS := parser.o lexer.o main.o utils.o
```

Pattern rules will deduce the `.c` (or whatever) file needed to build each `.o`.

Your `$(OBJS): $(SRCS)` rule is unnecessary and harmful. If it were actually populated with the names you expect, it would expand to something like this:

```
parser.o lexer.o main.o utils.o: parser.c lexer.c main.c utils.c
```

That's saying that each of the `.o` files on the left depends on each of the source files on the right.

You do not need this at all; make should have an implicit rule which says how to build an individual `.o` from a `.c`.

On the other hand, if you want a Makefile to support accurate incremental builds, you need dependencies: for each `.o` file, you need to specify what header files they depend on, not only what `.c` files.

Makefiles without dependencies beyond object file to source file only support a clean rebuild from scratch; they will not work right for development. When you edit some header file, the code will not rebuild.